# Parametrized Junit tests with Serenity reports

Tags: java, testing, junit, serenity-bdd

I ran into some trouble testing a Spring app. The current approach in my team is to write scenarios in Gherkin and have Serenity provide its pretty reports.

A new component in the app will need a lot of test cases. The requirements will be provided in a few 'parsable' excel files so I thought it would be neat to just use them directly, row by row, in a Junit parametrized test. Another option would be to write a bloated Gherkin feature and tediously compose each example manually.

So I thought of something like that:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
private static class Tests {
    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "...") // name with the params
    public static Collection params() {
         // parse excel here or use some other class to do it
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        /* do the actual test - it involves sending and receiving some JSON objects */
    }
}
```

This works smoothly but I ran into trouble trying to use

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
```

The problem is that Junit does not support multiple runners. A solution I found is to make a nested class and annotate each with a different runner, but I don't know how to make it work (which runner should be on the outside, where do I actually run the tests, an so on).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using? If I recall correctly, JUnit 5 added support for multiple runners via @ExtendWith.
 Check out (http://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration - section 3.5) and http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions

Comment: I actually found another solution, but thank you anyway. I am trying to make it work with JUnit 4 but what you suggested could probably also be a viable option - maybe we could use an upgrade ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Serenity provides another runner - `SerenityParameterizedRunner` which seems to have the same features as JUnit's `Parameterized`.